# how to update a mysql database from a dataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

[Picture of Visual Studio Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ1lA.png)

Hi,

Hope someone can help. I am trying to create a vehicle log for the company I work for. I have managed to get the dataGridView to add a row to the database but, This is what I have found on the internet and it seams to work. Can anyone tell me if this is the correct way of updating the MySQL database from a dataGridView?

NOTE: I added a timer tick so that if anyone added a new line, then the data in the dataGridView it automatically updates the MySQL database.

```
// saves the data in the dataGridView to the MySQL database
    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //int index = vehiclemovementDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index;
        //vehiclemovementDataGridView.Rows.
        vehiclemovementTableAdapter.Update(this.vehiclelogDataSet.vehiclemovement);
        //vehiclemovementDataGridView.Update(this.vehiclelogDataSet.vehiclemovement);
    }
```

In have not typed the connection to the database I added a dataGridView and configured it to connect the MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing should work according to [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171933.aspx)

But you could also try replacing the line:

```
vehiclemovementTableAdapter.Update(this.vehiclelogDataSet.vehiclemovement);
```

with

```
vehiclemovementTableAdapter.Update(vehiclemovementDataTable)
```

where **vehiclemovementDataTable** is the data table converted from the data grid view (You would have to add this code yourself). Either should be okay, however the way you are doing it is most likely better and more efficient.